# Amazon MWS Push Notifications

Tags: amazon-mws

I want to develop an app that allows the users of the app (sellers on Amazon), to send me a notification when they receive an order on Amazon (a notification containing informations about the order).

Is it possible?

Maybe only the seller can receive notifications about his account.

I think, if it's possible, I need a MWS and a AWS account.

In the documentation of MWS (https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/notifications/Notifications_Overview.html), there is:

> The Amazon MWS push notifications enable you to receive information
>   that is relevant to your business with Amazon without having to poll
>   the Amazon MWS service. Instead, the information is sent directly to
>   you when an event occurs to which you are subscribed. For more
>   information about how to subscribe to receive notifications, see
>   Subscriptions Overview in the Amazon MWS Subscriptions API section
>   reference.

Then, in the 'Subscriptions API' section:

> The Amazon MWS Subscriptions API section enables you to subscribe to
>   receive notifications that are relevant to your business with Amazon.
>   With the operations in the Subscriptions API section, you can register
>   to receive important information from Amazon without having to poll
>   the Amazon MWS service. Instead, the information is sent directly to
>   you when an event occurs to which you are subscribed.
>
> To receive notifications, you must first create and register a
>   Destination, such as an Amazon Simple Queue Service (Amazon SQS)
>   queue. Then, you create a Subscription for the NotificationType that
>   you want to receive, such as a notification when another Seller has
>   changed their offer for an item that you also sell. Finally, verify
>   that Amazon is able to send notifications to your Destination by
>   calling the SendTestNotificationToDestination operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at this time.  The only notification options are [AnyOfferChangedNotification](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/notifications/Notifications_AnyOfferChangedNotification.html), which sends an SQS message when any one of the top 20 offers for an ASIN changes, and [FulfillmentOrderStatusNotification](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/notifications/Notifications_FulfillmentOrderStatusNotification.html), which notifies you if there is a multi channel order status chance, and [FeePromotionNotification](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/notifications/Notifications_FeePromotionNotification.html).

This hasn't changed since I started using the AnyOfferChangedNotification several years ago.

One idea is to create an app that uses the [Orders API](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/orders-2013-09-01/Orders_Overview.html) periodically to check for orders, then you can have the app create the SQS message (or use another service altogether).  This would then notify you of a new order.

Comment: But can you please tell me that how is GetOrders API different from Subscriptions API? Like both of them do the same work except of the fact that Subscription API is used for Multi Channel Fulfillment. Now what is Multi Channel Fulfillment? I read the documentation and I am a little confused with these 2 API sections. Please can you explain it ?

Comment: The subscriptions API is for managing subscriptions.  Subscriptions are push notifications that Amazon can send to you.  If you subscribe, you can receive the notifications.  GetOrders is used to pull orders.  What I was mentioning above is that there isn't a push notification from Amazon that will tell you that you have a new order (not at least in 2017 when I wrote this).  What you can do is create your own by pulling with the Orders API and then notifying another app (through SQS or whatever queing service you want) that there are orders.

Comment: So in both the cases, I will have to create a scheduler that will regularly look for any updates in my order. Right? If it is so, which one do you is a better way to get order details?

Comment: Yes, depending on your needs, create a schedule to pull your orders and then do with them what you will.  Read the User Scenarios section at the bottom of the GetOrders link above for ideas but that page in general has lots of information on it.  It also talks about using the Reports API for bulk reporting.  Depending on your needs, there are operations there for you.  But as far as the original question, no there is nothing at Amazon that will tell you that you have orders....you have to pull.

Comment: Thank you so much. You helped me a lot. Can you tell me one more thing that if there are any APIs for cancelling the order or marking the order status as "Ready to Dispatch" or "Delivered"? In case of an FBA account, I think Amazon would do it but what will be the case for Merchant Fulfillment?

Comment: I think your answer is in submitting a feed with the correct order status.  It's been a long time, but I think this is what I used.  Read about the feed types here: https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_FeedType.html#FeedType_Enumeration__OrderFeeds

Comment: Yeah I think I was looking for this only. Thank you so much for your help. @ScottG

Comment: Can we not add a listener to the SQS Queue which would simply trigger my own service everytime a notification is added to the queue by Amazon? Can we use lambda function or eventBridge or anything like this? Please answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60705578/).